# window.open being flagged as a pop-up

Tags: javascript, jquery, api

I'm trying to figure out how I can bypass the pop blocking issue when using window.open. Here is the code I'm working on.

The first script I've built a script uses bit.ly API in shortening a URL address. Basically it gets the parameters then passes it to the API.

Then the second script calls the `get_short_url` function in order to share the bit.ly url via twitter using an `on-click` event. Unfortunately `window.open` seems to be flagged as a pop up by the browser. Is there way to bypass this

```
<script>
var base_url      = window.location.origin,
    hash_bang     = "/#/sign-up?referral=",
    login         = "login",
    api_key       = "api_key";


function get_short_url(login, api_key, func, value) {
    var value = document.getElementById('input-refcode').value;

    $.getJSON(
        "https://api-ssl.bitly.com//v3/shorten?callback=?", 
        { 
            "format": "json",
            "apiKey": api_key,
            "login": login,
            "longUrl": base_url + hash_bang + value
        },

        function(response)
        {
            func(response.data.url);
        }
    );
}
</script>
```

---

```
<script>

$('#twitter').on('click', function() {

    get_short_url(login, api_key, function(short_url) {
        win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up ' + short_url + ' to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us!' + ' https://www.electricstudio.ph/', '_blank');
        win.focus();
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't think so you can bypass that as it is a browser setting

Comment: @Saksham Is there a way to get the value from the first script and pass on the second script which is the `click event`.

Comment: @Saksham is right. as for your question to get the variable, one way is to save them is session.

Comment: @perseusl sorry for my ignorance but how to do that. Been constantly looking for answers.

Comment: getting and setting session is server side. so to do this, you need to create end point to set session and call it through ajax, then create an end point to get those session values and call it in your 2nd script

Answer (score 0):

I've got this working on Firefox, Chrome & internet explorer.

```js
var url = 'https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text='+encodeURIComponent('Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up xx to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us! https://www.electricstudio.ph/');
console.log(url);
var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
win.focus();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can bypass the popup alert as it is something which browser handles for safety. For your personal machine, you can change the security settings to mark this site as exception and then you won't be prompted again.

For your second part where you want to pass a value from on ajax call to another, you can create an object as below and pass it as a response

```
function(response)
{
    func({'shortURL' : response.data.url, 'yourValue': customValue });
}
```

And access this in your other function as

```
get_short_url(login, api_key, function(result) {
    var custVal = result.customValue;  //Your custom value
    win = window.open('https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=Get Free Rides at Electric Studio! Sign up ' + result.shortURL + ' to purchase your first timer package! After your first ride, you get 1 ride on us!' + ' https://www.electricstudio.ph/', '_blank');
    win.focus();
});
```